# for loop exception c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, runtime-error

For my C++ class I have to write a program that takes a phone number that contains letters (for example 1-800-GOFEDEX) from the user and returns the phone number with the actual number they should dial. I have my transformation logic inside a for loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    switch (letters[i]){
        case 'A':
        case 'B':
        case 'C':
            decodedNumber[i] = '2';
            continue;
        case 'D':
        case 'E':
        case 'F':
            decodedNumber[i] = '3';
            continue;
        case 'G':
        case 'H':
        case 'I':
            decodedNumber[i] = '4';
            continue;
        case 'J':
        case 'K':
        case 'L':
            decodedNumber[i] = '5';
            continue;
        case 'M':
        case 'N':
        case 'O':
            decodedNumber[i] = '6';
            continue;
        case 'P':
        case 'Q':
        case 'R':
        case 'S':
            decodedNumber[i] = '7';
            continue;
        case 'T':
        case 'U':
        case 'V':
            decodedNumber[i] = '8';
            continue;
        case 'W':
        case 'X':
        case 'Y':
        case 'Z':
            decodedNumber[i] = '9';
            continue;
        //the default will simply copy it over (in case there is a number mixed with the letters)
        default:
            decodedNumber[i] = i;
            continue;
    }
} //End of for loop
```

It compiles just fine, but when I run it, it will go through the loop once and then give me this error:

[image: runtime error]

I know it goes through the loop at least once because you can see the number 4 in the first position of the `decodedNumber` variable in this picture:

[image: Visual Studio During Debugging]

I have tried changing `i` to `i+1` in all my cases in the switch statement, but that didn't work either.

Any help is most appreciated!!!

[Here's the entire program code](https://github.com/H1tman1978/Phone-Decoder/tree/master) in case you need it

Comment: Post all errors here directly as text.

Comment: post the decleration of `decodedNumber` and the input way.

Comment: "BUYMORE" has seven letters. And you have `0 <= i <= 7` in your loop.

Comment: Can you change the continue statements to break statements and let the switch fall through naturally?  It shouldn't make a difference but to me continue is poor practice in this case, and would rule out a possibility.

Comment: Whenever you see `<=` in your code, consider that it is probably wrong.

Comment: *It compiles just fine* -- Since your new to programming, having the program "compile fine" buys you very little.  It only means that your program has no syntax errors, and an executable was created.  It has no bearing on whether your program is free of logical bugs.

Comment: BTW, you can do this without a `switch` statement.  Let `int index = letters[i] - A;` and `const int phone_digits[] = {2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9};`.  Then 'const dial_digit = phone_digits[index];`.  You have to use `if` statement to guard against unsupported characters.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews you can even do without a lookup table: `if (letters[i] < 'Z') decodedNumber[i] = (letters[i] - 'A')/3 + '2'`

Comment: `string decodedNumber=""` -- There is no `i`'th element in this string -- it's empty, thus you cannot access elements in it -- because there aren't any elements.    Second, please post your code here, not on a site that may go away at any moment.

Comment: @phuclv Obviously the formula won't work as PQRS and WXYZ have 4 letters for the same digits.

Comment: In your code, a comment like `//Variable is the letter l (el) not 1 (one)` does dot make sense. Use another letter for your variable name or better yet use a word like `index`.

Comment: @Phil1970 I have already checked for Z but I forgot about S. But it can be modified  easily to `(letters[i] - 'A' - (letters[i] > 'S'))/3  + '2'`. You can also add `- (letters[i] > 'Z')` to remove the check for 'Z' at the beginning

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Thank you to @PaulMcKenzie for directing me to the right area. I changed it to just declaring decodedNumber as a string and then on the next line I initialized it by setting it equal to the variable "letters" and that seemed to do the trick. For everyone else thanks and I'll try to make my questions better in the future, your feedback is appreciated!

Comment: @phuclv: `'A'`-`'Z'` are not guaranteed to be contiguous. (it is for Ansi, not for EBCDIC).

Comment: @Jarod42 yes but on on Windows and most modern systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr:

CHANGE line 25

```
string decodedNumber, returnedNumber.
```

ADD line 26

```
decodedNumber.resize(letters.size());
```

---

Ok, a few things.

1. Don't `use namespace std`. Get used to writing out `std::`.  This way, when you have multiple namespaces, you will not get confused between functions with identical names across them.
2. Line 22.  funtion should be function.
3. You are passing a string to switch, then trying to access it like a character array.  If you are playing with strings, use `letters.at(i)`.  `.at(i)` is safe, it will throw an exception when you walk off the end of the string.
4. The problem is that your string `decodedNumber = ""` is what throws the subscript error.  When you create that, it has a size of zero, which is, as imagined, no bueno.  Resize your string `decodedNumber.resize(letters.size())` should fix that.
5. The `continue` after every case is un-needed.
6. Watch your parens, please.  Please keep your formatting consistent.
7. I would personally replace

   ```
   while(running) {...}
   ```

   with

   ```
   do {...}
   while(running);
   ```

`do while` is guaranteed to run at least once, whereas `while` isn't.

Comment: Why do you say the `continue` after each case is unnecessary? Without that it will just fall into the next case statement. Admittedly I've never seen `continue` used here as I would always use `break` but you still need something to stop falling through to the next case.

Answer (score 1):

(A general suggestion)

If you set the look-up mechanism like, let's say (dial-pad description):

```
include <map>

// Dial-pad description:
const std::map<char, unsigned int> lut{
    {'1',1},
    {'2',2}, {'A',2}, {'B',2}, {'C',2},
    {'3',3}, {'D',3}, {'E',3}, {'F',3},
    {'4',4}, {'G',4}, {'H',4}, {'I',4},
    {'5',5}, {'J',5}, {'K',5}, {'L',5},
    {'6',6}, {'M',6}, {'N',6}, {'O',6},
    {'7',7}, {'P',7}, {'Q',7}, {'R',7}, {'S',7},
    {'8',8}, {'T',8}, {'U',8}, {'V',8},
    {'9',9}, {'W',9}, {'X',9}, {'Y',9}, {'Z',9},
    {'0',0}
};
```

Than, the code becomes simple: (and with a level of abstraction)

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string Dial{"1-800-GOFEDEX"};
std::vector<unsigned int> Number;

for (auto & Ch : Dial) {
    auto it = lut.find(Ch);
    if (it != lut.end())
        Number.push_back(it->second);
}
```

- In that case, you can also add support to other languages or other dial-pad variants, etc. without modifying your code (except the map initialization). Bilingual (0600-06FF value range of 2nd language) dial-pad, for example:

[image]

--

An alternative to the map `lut` (if "map efficiency" is an issue):

```
#include <array>
#include <climits>

std::array<unsigned int, 100> lut; // ASCII Code: '-' 45, '0'-'9': 48-57, 'A'-'Z': 65-90 
lut.fill(UINT_MAX);

// Dial-pad description:
lut['1'] = 1;
lut['2'] = lut['A'] = lut['B'] = lut['C'] = 2;
lut['3'] = lut['D'] = lut['E'] = lut['F'] = 3;
lut['4'] = lut['G'] = lut['H'] = lut['I'] = 4;
lut['5'] = lut['J'] = lut['K'] = lut['L'] = 5;
lut['6'] = lut['M'] = lut['N'] = lut['O'] = 6;
lut['7'] = lut['P'] = lut['Q'] = lut['R'] = lut['S'] = 7;
lut['8'] = lut['T'] = lut['U'] = lut['V'] = 8;
lut['9'] = lut['W'] = lut['X'] = lut['Y'] = lut['Z'] = 9;
lut['0'] = 0;
```

In that case, the code looks like:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string Dial{"1-800-GOFEDEX"};
std::vector<unsigned int> Number;

for (auto & Ch : Dial)
    if (lut[Ch] < 10)
        Number.push_back(lut[Ch]);
```

Comment: using a map for a linear range like this is inefficient. A lookup table like Thomas Matthews' solution would be better

Comment: Thanks @AmitG. for an interesting take on this. I don't have specific knowledge of countries outside of the US and if they do the vanity phone number like we do here in the US. However, the whole point of my program was to fulfill my assignment in my class which was to test the use of loops and what not, so I have to stick to a for loop with a switch/case statement. Thanks though!

Comment: @phuclv There are many considerations: not just efficiency. Also abstraction, code readability, maintenance, etc. One thing is to develop a Server, and another thing is to get an input from the user. Many times I find programmers that write code very efficient that no one, after 1/2 year, can understand, in place where efficiency has no importance. In any case, I added an array `lut`, in case that efficiency is an issue.

Comment: @phuclv: *"using a map for a linear range"* `'A'`-`'Z'` is not necessary a linear range :/

Comment: @AmitG.: For your map solution, if character is not in the `map`, you insert `0`. I would use `const map` and check presence with `find` (so you can even remove trick with `Skip`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I wanted to make full abstraction of the functionality from the data. It means that the lut describe valid chars only. Skip('-') is not a characteristic of the dial-pad; it's a characteristic of the user-input.

Comment: I meant `auto it = lut.find(Ch); if (it != lut.end()) { Number.push_back(it->second); }`. Currently, if '+' is in input, then it is replaced by `0` (as `Digit = lut['+'];` would insert default value).

Comment: @Jarod42 You got a point. I upgraded the code with your idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. As the comments saying, `for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)` may be wrong if `letters[i]` keep the string `"GOFEDEX"` when calling `letters[i]`. Though that is not always the case when `letters[7]` keeps an '\0' character, it is not good to loop to `i == 7`.
2. `decodedNumber[i]` may also throw array-index exceptions if the length of it is smaller than or equal to `i`. I guess it the reason because the exception is thrown in the line `decodedNumber[i] = '6';` when `i == 1`. The string `decodedNumber` have not had enough space to keep the new character, as `operator[]` won't allocate memory for strings.
3. `decodedNumber[i] = i;` maybe should be `decodedNumber[i] = letters[i];`.